# Java won't recognize string "-1" in line equation program. Check out the "equation" action command

Tags: java, math, line, equation

My Java progpram won't process -1 in a string correctly. It skips through all those if statements I have in the e.getActionCommand() for "equation". I tried making a character array from the string and processing character[0] and that didn't work either.

```
    if ("equation".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        if (interceptB != "0" && slopeX == "1")
        {
            if (strIntercept != "")
            {
                String slash = "[/]";
                String[] slashedUp = interceptB.split(slash);
                float numer = new Float(slashedUp[0]);
                float  denomer = new Float(slashedUp[1]);
                float fl = numer / denomer;
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (fl > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = x + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (fl < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = x - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                float numb = new Float(interceptB);
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (numb > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = x + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (numb < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = x - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (interceptB != "0" && slopeX == "-1")
        {
            if (strIntercept != "")
            {
                String slash = "[/]";
                String[] slashedUp = interceptB.split(slash);
                float numer = new Float(slashedUp[0]);
                float  denomer = new Float(slashedUp[1]);
                float fl = numer / denomer;
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (fl > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = -x + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (fl < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = -x - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                float numb = new Float(interceptB);
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (numb > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = -x + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (numb < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = -x - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (slopeX != "0" && interceptB == "0")
        {
            if (slopeX == "1")
            {
                textEquation.setText("y = x");
            }
            else if (slopeX == "-1")
            {
                textEquation.setText("y = -x");
            }
            else
            {
                textEquation.setText("y = " + slopeX + "x");
            }
        }
        else if (slopeX == "0" && interceptB != "0")
        {
            textEquation.setText("y = " + interceptB);
        }
        else
        {
            if (strIntercept != "")
            {
                String slash = "[/]";
                String[] slashedUp = interceptB.split(slash);
                float numer = new Float(slashedUp[0]);
                float  denomer = new Float(slashedUp[1]);
                float fl = numer / denomer;
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (fl > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = " + slopeX + "x" + " + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (fl < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = " + slopeX + "x" + " - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                float numb = new Float(interceptB);
                String minus = "[-]";
                String[] splitUp = interceptB.split(minus);
                if (numb > 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = " + slopeX + "x" + " + " + interceptB);
                }
                else if (numb < 0)
                {
                    textEquation.setText("y = " + slopeX + "x" + " - " + splitUp[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ("reset".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        point2.setEnabled(false);
        getSlope.setEnabled(false);
        getIntercept.setEnabled(false);
        totalEquation.setEnabled(false);
        firstPoint = null; 
        secondPoint = null; 
        slope = null;
        totalSlope = null;
        strIntercept = null; 
        slopeX = null; 
        interceptB = null;
        x1 = 0; 
        x2 = 0; 
        y1 = 0;
        y2 = 0; 
        slopex = 0; 
        slopey = 0; 
        simplifiedSlope = 0; 
        mx = 0; 
        totalMx = 0; 
        intercept = 0; 
        ySide = 0; 
        totalY = 0;
        textField1.setText("");
        textField2.setText("");
        textSlope.setText("");
        textIntercept.setText("");
        textEquation.setText("");
    }
}

public void GetFirstPoint()
{
    firstPoint = textField1.getText();
    String comma = "[,]";
    String[] x1Y1 = firstPoint.split(comma);
    x1 = new Float(x1Y1[0]);
    y1 = new Float(x1Y1[1]);
}

public void GetSecondPoint()
{
    secondPoint = textField2.getText();
    String comma = "[,]";
    String[] x2y2 = secondPoint.split(comma);
    x2 = new Float(x2y2[0]);
    y2 = new Float(x2y2[1]);
}   

public void GetSlope()
{
    slopey = y2 - y1;
    slopex = x2 - x1;

    if (slopey < 0 && slopex < 0)
    {
        slopey = -slopey;
        slopex = -slopex;
    }
    if (slopex < 0)
    {
        slopey = -slopey;
        slopex = -slopex;
    }
    int slopeGCF = calcGCF(slopey, slopex);

    if (slopey % slopex == 0)
    {
        simplifiedSlope = (int)slopey/(int)slopex;
        totalSlope = "";
    }
    else if (slopey % slopex != 0 && slopeGCF > 0)
    {
        slopey = slopey / slopeGCF;
        slopex = slopex / slopeGCF;
        String slopeY = RoundUp(slopey);
        String slopeX = RoundUp(slopex);
        totalSlope = slopeY + "/" + slopeX;
    }
    else
    {
        String slopeY = RoundUp(slopey);
        String slopeX = RoundUp(slopex);
        totalSlope = slopeY + "/" + slopeX;
    }
}

public void GetIntercept()
{
    if (totalSlope == "")
    {
        mx = simplifiedSlope * x1;
        intercept = y1 - mx;
        strIntercept = "";
    }

    else if (totalSlope != "")
    {
        mx = slopey * x1;

        if (mx % slopex == 0)
        {
            totalMx = mx / slopex;
            intercept = y1 - totalMx;
            strIntercept = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ySide = y1 * slopex;
            totalY = ySide - mx;
            float interceptGCF = calcGCF(totalY, slopex);
            float ceptGCFx = 0;
            float ceptGCFy = 0;
            if (totalY % slopex == 0)
            {
                intercept = (int)totalY / (int)slopex;
                strIntercept = "";
            }

            else if (totalY % slopex != 0 && interceptGCF > 0)
            {
                ceptGCFy = totalY / interceptGCF;
                ceptGCFx = slopex / interceptGCF;
                strIntercept = RoundUp(ceptGCFy) + "/" + RoundUp(ceptGCFx);
            }
            else
            {
                strIntercept = RoundUp(totalY) + "/" + RoundUp(slopex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public int calcGCF(float num, float denom)
{   
    float s;

    if (num < 0)
    {
        num = -num;
    }

    else if (denom < 0)
    {
        denom = -denom;
    }

    if (num > denom)
    {
        s = denom;
    }

    else
    {
        s = num;
    }

    if (s > 0)
    {
        for (float i = s; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if ((num % i == 0) && (denom % i == 0))
            {
                return (int)i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public String RoundUp(float f)
{
    int i = (int)f;
    String valToStore = (i==f) ? String.valueOf(i) : String.valueOf(f);
    return valToStore;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you trim the code down to just the relevant part?  That is a ton of code.

Comment: With James' request, I suggest you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: trimmed it this is in the actionPerformed module

Comment: @SeanSasaki "Trimming" doesn't mean "only all the code I care about", it means "the smallest unit of code that demonstrates the problem". In this case, *any* command/value recognition, since it all has the same problem. All that code is essentially identical from a logical/flow standpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String comparisons should use `"foo".equals(s)`, not `==`.

*(You have a **lot** of refactoring possibilities; it'd make the code **much** easier to reason about.)*

Comment: sorry i'm really new to Java but what does "foo" mean?

Comment: @SeanSasaki It's a string. It doesn't mean anything. Things in quotes are strings.

Comment: It's just an example string, the syntax is `someString.equals(anotherString)`.

Comment: @SeanSasaki Foo is a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). It's used as a placeholder for some arbitrary value.

Comment: @Sean `Foo`, `bar`, `baz` or `foobar` are just place holder variables for short code examples where you can't use any sensible names. [Quite a long and interesting history it has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo).

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.equals()` instead of `==` to compare strings. If all strings are known at compile time, or interned, comparison with `==`may succeeed, but in general it doesn't, because `==` compares the object references and not the contents.